# Powershell - add a formula to a column in a csv

Tags: powershell, csv, array-formulas

I have a .csv extract that I need to add a formula that fills down the column.  My csv data has a few hundred lines. One of the lines looks like this

in four columns A through D
Clarendon  -    Kitchen - ClarendonKitchen -    76933

What I need to do is add a formula in Column E which is 
=IF(ISBLANK(D2),"503-916-2000",IF(LEFT(D2,1)="6",CONCATENATE("503-916-",RIGHT(D2,4),"      ",", x",D2),CONCATENATE("503-916-2000 ","    "," , x",D2)))

I need that to go into E2, E3, E4....E5107 
The result would be 
Columns A Through  E 
Clarendon - Kitchen -   ClarendonKitchen -  76933  -  503-916-2000  , x76933

Can this be done with Powershell?  If so, how? 
Thank you! 
Eydie

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: CSV files don't allow for formulae - they're plain text, data only. Do you need to create a new column in the CSV file that contains the result of the specified calculation?

Answer (score -2):

I would use the latest Powershell Excel Module

https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel

There clear examples on how to use the Module to do what you wish.

https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=formula